# Unable to build OIS with MinGW (as a part of Ogre3D dependencies)

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, ogre

I want to build Ogre3D (v 1.9) library (as there is no recently precompiled one) using the MinGW toolchain.

Versions of all stuff:
- MinGW 4.9.2
- CMake 3.4

Ogre3D dependencies use:
- Cg 3.1
- FreeImage 3.15.3
- freetype 2.4.9
- OIS 1.4
- SDL2 2.0.3
- zlib 1.2.8
- zziplib 0.13.62
- Microsoft DirectX SDK June 2010 (not included in the dependencies pack = needed do download and install on my own)

**I am currently stuck on building the Ogre dependencies. Everything builds fine except OIS.**

Here is the problem:
[Screenshot of make all errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0wbj.png)

I used [these](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Specific%20Build%20Guides) three specific guides on Ogre's Wiki page, but all of them are outdated, in some cases they don't even match the folder structure.

//EDIT:
here are 2 lines from build.make (the one in error + next line)

```
@$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=C:\ogredeps\build\CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_21) "Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\OIS.dll"  
cd /d C:\ogredeps\build\src\ois && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\OIS.dir\link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

Comment: What is the concrete step that is failing (*build.make* line 585)? That might help with figuring out the issue.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand this question. The only thing that I know is that my compiler can't properly read one file from MS DX SDK

Comment: The error message from your screenshots tells you exactly which build command caused the error. Checking out the actual error might help in giving clues as to the reason. Therefore checking the *build.make* file line 585 might help in narrowing it down, although I already assume it is the below mentioned *binutils* issue.

Comment: I face the same problem, but i use TDM-mingw64, absolutely same problem, i'm going to check bintuils:/

Comment: I have upgraded my MinGW to 4.9.3, I might try to compile it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *binutils* version 2.25 (part of MinGW), there was an issue that prevented it from handling **.lib* files created with VS2013. That might hold true for the d*input8.lib* file that is trying to be used in the make process.

[This issue](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17910) should be fixed in *bintuils* version 2.25.1. Please upgrade your MinGW instance to this tool version and try again.

Comment: Can you explain me how exactly I can upgrade my compiler? I used to just replace MinGW directory but _bintuils_ is a new word for me

Comment: I downloaded archive called binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz but it contains tons of scary files I do not know what do do with, even after reading readmes.

Comment: Not a MinGW user, so not completely sure. I would assume that you should be able to replace the old *binutils* elements with the new ones (probably in the */MinGW/bin* folder). Best make a backup first.